# Anyone know of a "N71" Hall Effect Thruster currently in production or development?

Tags: propulsion, engines, ion-thruster

In a NASA Goddard Q&A transcript for an upcoming proposal, the NASA representative mentioned that the mission designers were considering the "N71" Hall Effect Thruster as an option for an upcoming mission.  I've never heard of this and my and my colleague's google skills were insufficient to the task of uncovering any information about such a device.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I see a lot of N71's here, could it be referring to an accession number rather than a model number? https://books.google.com/books?id=UjUrAAAAIAAJ&pg=SL1-PA91&lpg=SL1-PA91&dq=N71+thruster&source=bl&ots=6Lf0Qy78EC&sig=ACfU3U1jwufvqeKmemjKo6WZFR9cS7gXXw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLr6bjg_vpAhUKc5QKHauqCzAQ6AEwC3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=N71%20thruster&f=false and [here's one example](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19710001989.pdf)

Comment: Unfortunately all of those N71 references mean a NASA publication from 1971, so they would not be referring to a current, modern ion engine.  Those were the only sorts of hits I was getting as well.